# Understanding SUM(NULL) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null, sum

Usually when `NULL` is involved in any equation then the whole result resolves into `NULL` (e.g. `SELECT 2 + NULL + 5` returns `NULL`)

Same holds for the following case:

`SELECT SUM(NULL)` returns `NULL`. `Proposition #1`

What happens when `SUM` is used to aggregate a column and the column can contain `NULL` values too ?

Based on the `proposition #1` why the output doesn't result in `NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE t (age INT NULL);

INSERT INTO t (age)  VALUES (15),(20), (NULL), (30), (35);

SELECT 
SUM(age)
FROM t;
```

**Output:** `100`

But I was expecting `NULL`.

*Does MySQL silently skips those NULL values in this case?*

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f99bb/2

Comment: A column with the value `NULL` is basically `EMPTY`, which means its not taken into the calculation for SUM. A lot of database schemas use `NULL` as the empty value. Imagine those wouldnt be able to calculate the `SUM` of their other columns anymore.

Comment: @Xatenev then as he pointed, `SELECT 2 + NULL + 5` should be `7`;

Comment: No. It returns `NULL` @Jigar

Comment: @Jigar No - because `SUM` is not involved in that case, and so - this just ends up in a normal math calculation, instead of a method that skips out the `NULL` values

Comment: @Xatenev okay. got it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well it's explained in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

> **SUM([DISTINCT] expr)**
>   Returns the sum of expr. If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns
>   NULL. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to sum only the distinct values
>   of expr.
>
> SUM() returns NULL if there were no matching rows.

What's more it's also said that:

> This section describes group (aggregate) functions that operate on
>   sets of values. Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL
>   values.

in other words SUM behaves like this because that's the way it's defined to be.

Comment: The DISTINCT keyword can be used to sum only the distinct values of **expr** - Does this line exclude `NULL`? I've gone through the documentation before posting and didn't understand the strength of this line. Doesn't `NULL` fall into `DISTINCT` ?

Comment: when you use distinct in this context, again you are talking of non null values because by definition nulls are ignored here

Comment: Answer lies in this line **This section describes group (aggregate) functions that operate on sets of values. Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values**. :) Missed that :(. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

You are right, aggregate functions handles null values in a different way than non aggregate functions:

```
select 2 + NULL + 5
```

returns NULL because NULL on this context it means an unknown value, so the result will be NULL (unknown) as well.

This will return 7 instead:

```
select SUM(n)
from (
  select 2 as n
  union all select null
  union all select 5
) s
```

because on this context a NULL value, even if it is unknown, can be seen as a "not specified value". The reason is that it's very common to use NULL as a not specified value and it's little pratical use to include NULLs in an aggregate function, that's why aggregate functions are defined to ignore NULLs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice way to separate `Aggregate` & `Non Aggregate` examples. I wish I could accept both the answers. Anyway, upvote